# Macro to revert to first tab in Excel after 15 minutes of inactivity

Tags: vba, excel, user-inactivity

I have a shared excel workbook that our department gets into everyday and that is displayed on an external monitor for everyone to look at. I would like to create a macro for the spreadsheet that makes it so that after 15 minutes of inactivity, the page is sent back to the first tab (the homepage). Is this achievable? I did some research and was not able to find a solution but I am new to Excel VBA so I could easily be missing it.

Comment: Some googling brought me to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243861%28v=office.12%29.aspx), which explains how you can use a hidden form to track user inactivity. Might be a good starting point for what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You would set a timer to call a function. A 1 minute timer would allow you to do maths.

Measuring inactivity is difficult. But if you can just say a few things to simplify what is inactivity.

If you look in ObjectViewer forthe Application object, you'll see all the events. Intercept likely ones (like change or calculate) and cancel your 15 min counter. Your timer increases the counter till > 15 min then changes sheet. The event(s) set counter to 0.